# ExtJS paging grid filters only the first page

Tags: extjs, filter, grid, paging

I am working on a grid which uses filters, but it only filters the first page. When I click 'next' it forgets about my filters and loads the next set of records. How do I make it remember the filter even if I click 'next' to load the next set of records from paging?

Thanks,
SS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the filter parameters into the store's `baseParams`.  Passing your filter parameters in the `load` call on the store will only use them for the first load call — subsequent calls made by the paging toolbar won't pass them.

```
store.setBaseParam('query', 'search-text'); // always send 'query'
store.load({ params: { start: 0, limit: 40 } });
// this will send:
// { query: 'search-text', start: 0, limit: 40 }

store.load({ params: { query: 'bob', start: 41, limit: 40 } });
// baseParams overridden by load params
// { query: 'bob', start: 41, limit: 40 }

store.load();  // only sends baseParams
// { query: 'search-text' }
```

The ExtJS `Ext.data.Store` [docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store) have the details.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks WES I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score -1):

Setting the `baseParams`, like in the answer above, is only for EXTJS 3.x or less.
For EXTJS 4.xx, we must add in the store's proxy, an `extraParam` with  your query:
 `store.getProxy().extraParam= A JSON ENCODED QUERY`
like:
 `store.getProxy().extraParam= Ext.JSON.encode({'sort':[{'id':'ASC'}]})`
For a proper configuration, investigate the your request, in your navigator developer's tools or in your backend